# Two questions on eigenvalue theory

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $6.)$ The vector $v = (1,−2,1)$ is an eigenvector of the real matrix
>
> $$A =\begin{bmatrix}
> a &b& c\\
> 4& 1& 2\\
> d& e& f
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^3$ with corresponding eigenvalue
>
> (A) $64$
>
> (B) $−8$
>
> (C) $1$
>
> (D) $8$
>
> (E) $−1$
>
> Answer: B
>
> $7.)$ Suppose that $A$ is a $3\times 3$ real matrix with $k$ distinct real eigenvalues and $l$ distinct complex (i.e., non-real) eigenvalues. Consider the following statements:
>
> (i) $k = 2,\ l = 0$
>
> (ii) $k = 0,\ l = 3$
>
> (iii) $k = 1,\ l = 2$
>
> (iv) $k = 2,\ l = 1$
>
> How many of the above statements are possible?
>
> (A) None
>
> (B) $1$
>
> (C) $2$
>
> (D) $3$
>
> (E) All of them
>
> Answer: C

For $6.)$ I know $A$ times the eigenvalue gives $\lambda$ times the eigenvector but the matrix has letters in it and I cant seem to get the right and when I multiply $A$ by the eigenvalue.

For $7.)$ do you multiply the top by the conjugate?

Comment: For 7, we can simply refer to the characteristic equation and remark that all complex roots come in conjugate pairs. Thus there must be an even number of them and we also know that in an algebraically closed field a 3x3 matrix has 3 roots.

Comment: do the l's come with 2 because there complex

Comment: For 6, $Av = (?, 4, ?)$, so the eigenvalue is ... .

Comment: oh it was originally from a 4 so they took out a 2 so that must be the eigenvalue. Thankyou

Comment: $-2$. BTW, you have to put "@username" if you want "username" to be notified (eg. if you are asking for explanation).

Comment: Yes that's what I wrote. 2's or 0 for complex roots

Answer (score 0):

6) Since $Av = \lambda v $ then

$A^3v = A^2 Av = A^2 (\lambda v) = .... = \lambda^3 v $

But then

$4 (1) + 1 (-2) + 2 (1) = 4 = -2 \lambda$ which implies $\lambda = -2$ hence $\lambda^3 = -8$.

7) take $det (A - \lambda I) = 0$ which in a $3 \times 3$ matrix is a 3rd degree polynomial of the form $p (\lambda) = a_3 \lambda^3 + a_2 \lambda^2 + a_1 \lambda + a_0$

Over any algebraically closed field this polynomial has at least one root. Specifically over the Complex field it has 3 roots. If any of those roots happen to be complex numbers (not real), then we know from the Complex Conjugate Pair Theorem that the conjugate of that root is also a root. Thus $l $ is even (where 0 is an even number).

So we can tease out the answer (even though we don't know the field). (i) can be true since we could have a repeat real root and a separate distinct root. (ii) cannot be true since there cannot be an odd number of roots. (iii) works fine, 1 real 2 complex roots. (iv) fails since there is a lone complex root without its conjugate.